# What is a wordpress instance

Tags: installation

People are referring to the WordPress platform as the "WordPress instance". What do they mean by this? I've done some research but I couldn't find anything

Thanks in advance

Comment: English baby :-)

**instance**
ˈɪnst(ə)ns/Submit
noun

1.
an example or single occurrence of something.
"a serious instance of corruption"
synonyms: example, occasion, occurrence, case, representative case, typical case, case in point, illustration, specimen, sample, exemplar, exemplification
"there was not a single instance of religious persecution"

---- 

**Basically an instance is a single installation in short. So a WordPress instance is a single installation of WordPress.**

Comment: why not to ask those people?

Answer (score 3):

Basically an instance is a single installation in short. So a WordPress instance is a single installation of WordPress.

**instance**
ˈɪnst(ə)ns/Submit
noun

1.
an example or single occurrence of something.
synonyms:   example, occasion, occurrence, case, representative case, typical case, case in point, illustration, specimen, sample, exemplar, exemplification
"there was not a single instance of religious persecution"

---